Heisenberg uncertainty principle and QKD protocols
Some Quantum Key Distribution (QKD) protocols, like the well-known BB84, are said to be based on the uncertainty principle which I assume it to be the Heisenberg principle.
This one states that two obervables $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ which do not commute
cannot be measured in the same time with arbitrary accuracy :
\begin{equation}
\Delta \hat{A} \times \Delta \hat{B} \ge \frac{1}{2}|\langle [\hat{A}\hat{B}]\rangle_{\varphi}|   \qquad (1)
\end{equation}
where

$\Delta \hat{U}^{2} = \langle\hat{U}^{2}\rangle_{\varphi} - (\langle U \rangle_{\varphi})^{2}$,
$[\hat{A}\hat{B}] = \hat{A}\hat{B} - \hat{B}\hat{A}$

and the well-known example is with $\hat{A}=\hat{x}$ and $\hat{B}=\hat{p}_{x}$ :
\begin{equation}
\Delta\hat{x}\Delta\hat{p}_{x}\ge \frac{\hbar}{2}
\end{equation}
However, I wonder when this principle is actually used in the BB84 related protocols. What is used in these protocols is that conjugated bases for one qubit are used.
As an example, for one photon, both bases $\{|H\rangle ,|V\rangle \}$ and $\{|D\rangle ,|A\rangle \}$ are used because, setting one photon in one of the vectors of first basis, $|H\rangle$ or $|V\rangle$, and measuring in the other basis leads to maximal uncertainty, i.e. probability to get upon measurement either $|D\rangle$ or $|A\rangle$ is $1/2$ for both or in other words, the Shannon entropy is maximal :
\begin{equation}
H(X) = - \sum_{x}P(X=x)\log_2{[P(X=x)]} = 1
\end{equation}
Is my understanding correct ? that BB84 related protocols do not use the Heisenberg uncertainty principle as formulated by (1) ? But could some QKD protocols be really based on (1) ?

Having dug a little, I think the correct answer should come from Quantum Optics, it seems indeed there is a similar Heisenberg uncertainty relationship between the number of photons ($N$) and the photon phase ($\delta$) : $\Delta N\times \Delta \delta \ge \hbar / 2$ which states that the better you want to count photons, the less well you will be able to measure their phases, and conversely. But I let other people develop as this just an insight.
